# JMockit verify if private method is called

Tags: java, jmockit

I am testig a public method and I want to verify if a private method, that have mocked params, is called.
All the answers I have found are using invoke method, but this was removed since JMockit v1.36

```
public class ClassToTest{

   public void methodToTest(){
     DependencyClass abc = new DependencyClass();
     if(privateMethod1()){
        privateMethod2(abc);
     }
   }
   
   private boolean privateMethod1(){ return true; }
   
   private void privateMethod2(DependencyClass abc){ abc.doStuff(); }
}
```

```
public class testClassToTest{
   
   @Mocked
   DependencyClass abc;
   
   @Tested 
   ClassToTest testedClass;

   @BeforeEach
   public void setUp() { 
     testedClass = new ClassToTest();
   }
    
   @Test
   public void testMethod(){
        new MockUp<ClassToTest>() {
            @Mock
            private boolean privateMethod1() {
                return true;
            }
        };
        
        testedClass.methodToTest();

        new FullVerificationsInOrder() {{
            abc = new DependencyClass();
            //Check here if privateMethod2(abc) gets called once
        }};
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Powermock to mock and verify private methods.

Please check https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/MockPrivate

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways:

1. To level up your method's scope from private to package-private and after it, your method will become visible in the test.
2. Refactoring your code and encapsulate the private method to Predicate and after it, you can test your primary method and Predicate separately.

You can't test the private method by Junit.